# Makefile error when trying to build core-image-minimal with custom DTB

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, yocto, imx6

I'm new to the Yocto Project and I'm trying to build a simple core-image-minimal image for my custom board based on i.MX6QP/Q/DL SABRE Automotive. Right now I'm only working with the meta-freescale layer.

I have some custom DTS files that I want build and include in a fitImage of the Linux kernel.

This is what I've done so far:

1. I've created a custom layer with a custom machine, and in the **conf/machine.conf** file I have specified the DTBs that I want to use:

   ```
   KERNEL_DEVICETREE = " \
       imx6qp-g25-protoc-1280x480.dtb \
       ...
   "
   ```
2. I've created a **linux-fslc-imx_%.bbappend** file in **/yocto/poky/meta-custom/recipes-kernel/linux/** that references a **.patch** file that contains the git diff like [done here](https://github.com/yoctocookbook/meta-bsp-custom/blob/master/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-wandboard-3.10.17/0001-ARM-dts-Add-wandboard-custom-dts-file.patch). In the .patch file I've included the required **arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile** modifications and the DTS files.

Unfortunately, when trying to build core-image-minimal, the DTB building fails with this message:

> make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/arm/boot/dts/imx6qp-g25-protoc-1280x480.dtb'.  Stop.
>   arch/arm/Makefile:322: recipe for target 'imx6qp-g25-protoc-1280x480.dtb' failed
>   make[2]:**  [imx6qp-g25-protoc-1280x480.dtb] Error 2
>   Makefile:146: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
>   make[1]:  **[sub-make] Error 2
>   Makefile:24: recipe for target '__sub-make' failed
>   make: *** [__sub-make] Error 2
>   ERROR: oe_runmake failed
>   WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

I've checked that the patch is applied, in fact, by looking at the source folder *linux-fslc-imx/4.1-2.0.x+gitAUTOINC+6c1ad49339-r0/build/source/arch/arm/boot/dts*, the **Makefile** is correct and the **DTS** files are present.

Comment: Why is there an illegal character ("<") in the target filename?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I inserted the '<' by mistake while enabling the blockquote. I edited the question.

Comment: How do you verified patch is applied ? using `devshell` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue was that I was not including a **defconfig** file in the kernel recipe, so the `CONFIG_SOC_IMX6Q` variable was not set to `y` making my target undetected in the **arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile**. Including a **defconfig** with `ARCH_SOC_IMX6Q=y` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively a config file **imx6q.cfg** with this option inside:

```
ARCH_SOC_IMX6Q=y
```

can be created and placed next to the **linux-xxx.bb** recipe down into **files** subfolder.

in this case, any **defconfig** supplied with the kernel will have necessary option enabled before the compilation or any patch applied.

use the following example on how to to append created config file inside the **linux-xxx.bb** recipe:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git;protocol=git;nocheckout=1;name=machine;branch=linux-5.4.y; \
           file://imx6q.cfg"
```